# Error: ER_DATA_TOO_LONG: Data too long for column 'img'

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, base64

Hola amigos estoy convirtiendo imagenes en base64 para poder insertarlas en una tabla de sql, pero tengo algunos problemas, al parecer algunos archivos en base64 son más largos  que el máximo de caracteres que puedo guardar... mi error es el siguiente:

> 109380
>   (node:6688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_DATA_TOO_LONG: Data too long for column 'img' at row 1

**109380** es el numero de caracteres que tiene mi objeto **img** y sql lo máximo por tabla que me permite es meter 50,000 caracteres [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como puedo reducir el tamaño de mi base64 o si depende de las proporciones de la imagen,o si hay algo que pueda hacer con sql para mejorar ese aspecto, estoy usando **MAMP**?
Ya descubrí, que si es por el tamaño de mi imagen, necesito saber que hacer para guardar archivos más grandes?

Esto es lo que hago para convertirlo

```js
const img64 = image2base64('uploads/' + originalname).then(
  (resp) => {
    console.log('image converted');
    newUser.img = resp;
    console.log(resp.length)
    // console.log(newUser);
  }
).catch(
  (errs) => {
    console.log(errs)
  }
);
```

Comment: Hola, ¿es necesario que tu campo sea tipo `varbinary`? Pregunto eso porque pudieras usar el tipo `blob` o si hiciera falta, el tipo `longblob`.

Comment: Genial mil gracias, ya sabes si quieres la respuesta posteala,  btw eres una pistola mi Mau :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Es necesario que tu campo sea tipo `varbinary`? Pregunto eso porque pudieras usar el tipo `blob` o si hiciera falta, el tipo `longblob`. Ya que permiten almacenar mayor cantidad de información. En el caso de `blob` puedes almacenar archivos de hasta 2^16 (65.536) bytes y en el caso de `longblob` hasta 2^32 (4.294.967.296) bytes.

Debes tomar en cuenta además el requerimiento de espacio al almacenar datos tipo `blob`.

Puedes consultar la documentación en [Data Type Storage Requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

Espero te sea de ayuda.